# perl or awk: zero proof division with perl or awk

Tags: perl, awk

I have to add a field showing the difference in percentage between 2 fields in a file like:

```
BI,1266,908
BIL,494,414
BKC,597,380
BOOM,2638,654
BRER,1453,1525
BRIG,1080,763
DCLE,0,775
```

The output should be:

```
BI,1266,908,-28.3%
BIL,494,414,-16.2%
BKC,597,380,-36.35%
BOOM,2638,654,-75.2%
BRER,1453,1525,5%
BRIG,1080,763,-29.4%
DCLE,0,775,-
```

Note the zero in the last row. Either of these fields could be zero. If a zero is present in either field, N/A or - is acceptable.

What I'm trying --

Perl:

```
perl -F, -ane 'if ($F[2] > 0 || $F[3] > 0){print $F[0],",",$F[1],",",$F[2],100*($F[2]/$F[3])}' file
```

I get `Illegal division by zero at -e line 1, <> line 2.` If I change the `||` to `&&` it prints nothing.

In awk:

```
awk '$2>0{$4=sprintf("%d(%.2f%)", $3, ($3/$2)*100)}1' file
```

Just prints the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, '$2 == 0 || $3 == 0 { printf("%s,-\n", $0); next }
           { printf("%s,%.2f%%\n", $0, 100 * ($3 / $2) - 100) }' input.csv
BI,1266,908,-28.28%
BIL,494,414,-16.19%
BKC,597,380,-36.35%
BOOM,2638,654,-75.21%
BRER,1453,1525,4.96%
BRIG,1080,763,-29.35%
DCLE,0,775,-
```

How it works: if the second or third columns are equal to 0, add a `-` field to the line. Otherwise, calculate the percentage difference and add that.

Answer (score 3):

Your perl's main issue was confusing awk's 1-based column indexes with perl's 0-based column indexes.

```
 perl -F, -ane 'print "$1," if /(.+)/;if ($F[1] > 0 && $F[2] > 0){printf ("%.2f%", ((100*$F[2]/$F[1])-100)) } else {print "-"};print "\n"' file
```

The `$1` here refers to the capture group `(.+)` which means "The whole line but the linefeed".  The rest is probably self-explanatory if you understand the awk.

Answer (score 2):

You're not telling awk that the fields are separated by commas so it's assuming the default, spaces, and so $2 is never greater than zero because it's null as there's only 1 space-separated field per line. Change it to:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $2>0{$4=sprintf("%d(%.2f%)", $3, ($3/$2)*100)}1' file
BI,1266,908,908(71.72%)
BIL,494,414,414(83.81%)
BKC,597,380,380(63.65%)
BOOM,2638,654,654(24.79%)
BRER,1453,1525,1525(104.96%)
BRIG,1080,763,763(70.65%)
DCLE,0,775
```

and then tweak it for your desired output:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$4=($2 && $3 ? sprintf("%.2f%", (($3/$2)-1)*100) : "N/A")} 1' file
BI,1266,908,-28.28%
BIL,494,414,-16.19%
BKC,597,380,-36.35%
BOOM,2638,654,-75.21%
BRER,1453,1525,4.96%
BRIG,1080,763,-29.35%
DCLE,0,775,N/A
```

Comment: The cleanest solution I'd say -- why not do their actual "_desired output_", `($3/$2-1)*100`...?

Comment: @zdim I didn't notice a difference, I was just focused on fixing their awk code to do what they were trying to do with it. Fixed now, thanks.